# Mostrar datos de un input type text en tabla con PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

Quisiera saber como puedo capturar los datos de un input type text insertados en la BD MySQL y mostrarlos en una tabla con PHP usando un array, ya que con los demás inputs me funciona correctamente pero no me resulta con el input type text, les dejo el código:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="Desc" placeholder="Ingresar texto" name="Desc" autofocus required>
```

PHP:

```
<?php while ($producto = $result->fetch_assoc()){ ?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $producto['Descripción']; ?></td>

</tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Insertar en la BD:

```
$Descripción = $_POST['Desc'];

    $stmt = $bd->prepare("
        INSERT INTO producto (Id, Stock, Tipo, Disponible, Valor, Descripción) 
        VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
        ");

//Asigna las variables a la query
    $stmt->bind_param('isssis', $Id, $Stock, $Tipo, $Disponible, $Valor, $Descripción);

//Ejecuta la query
    $stmt->execute();
```

Comment: No es muy recomendable usar tildes en variables o campos. Puede que por eso no te funcione.

Comment: @Juanant eso no tiene nada que ver, es más, recomiendas una **mala práctica** en tu propuesta, pues se está usando el estilo orientado a objetos y tú recomiendas mezclarlo con el estilo procedural. El problema parece ser a todas luces el acento en la palabra `Descripción`. No se recomienda usar acentos, ni en los nombres de columnas ni en variables. Nada más con que no pongas una codificación adecuada como `utf-8` el código podría fallar porque no va a reconocer los acentos. La solución es: evitar acentos y siempre establecer una codificación adecuada. Prueba a hacer un `var_dump($producto);`

Comment: Estimados, muchísimas gracias, en efecto el problema eran los acentos, quité todos los acentos y me funcionó correctamente, nuevamente muchísimas gracias! :D